# scrolling down in selenium while more Data loads- Lazy loading

Tags: selenium, scroll, loading, lazy-evaluation

Hi I have written a code to scroll down a page using the following :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

However, it scrolls only once, while more data loads on my page. The data is enclosed inside a div tag.

When it scrolls down, The page shows loading and loads more data (Lazy loading).
How do i implement scrolling for lazy loading in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here example how you can scroll until size of data elements not change. To get loadingLocator open chrome devtools, scroll and press F8, it will pause and you'll able to get selector.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

int dataSize = driver.findElements(dataLocator).size();
while (true){
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(loadingLocator));

    if (driver.findElements(dataLocator).size()== dataSize)
        break;
    dataSize = driver.findElements(dataLocator).size();
}
```

Also you can implement your own wait like below:

```
By dataLocator = By.cssSelector(".save_ride_container");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 500);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

AtomicInteger dataSize = new AtomicInteger(driver.findElements(dataLocator).size());
boolean complete = false;
while (!complete){
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
    complete = wait.ignoring(TimeoutException.class)
            .until(d -> {
                int size = driver.findElements(dataLocator).size();
                if (size== dataSize.get())
                    return true;
                dataSize.set(size);
                return false;
            });
}

List<WebElement> passengers = driver.findElements(dataLocator);
passengers.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.findElement(By.xpath("./div[1]/div[3]/p[5]/strong"))));
```

Comment: Here Data Locator is my Div tag or is it anything else? As there are multiple div tags on my page. for eg. facebook friend list has multple div tags

Comment: @Radhika any short and stable tag you use to get list of friends.

Comment: Thanks.. my page contains 10 div tags All having xpath as follows: //div[@class="save_ride_container"]. On lazy loading 10 more div elements load. Can you please tell me how do i fit this into my code

Comment: This div tag has an ID (i.e. unique for every div tag and follows no sequence), has a passenger name div tag inside of it as follows: //*[@id="100452"]/div[1]/div[3]/p[5]/strong

Comment: can you please guide me further?

Comment: @Radhika for dataLocator you can use `.save_ride_container`instead of `//div[@class="save_ride_container"]`.  After you get list of data you'll need iterate throw and get passenger name for each.

Comment: Thanks alot Sers. Shall try the same and get back to you